# Why is the first character of this in place string reversal function not changing?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I wrote this small piece of code to reverse a string in place.

```
#include "template.h"

void main()     {
        char temp;
        char *str = NULL;
        int read, i;
        size_t len = 20;


        read = getline(&str, &len, stdin);
        if (read > -1)
        {
                str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';
                for (i = 0; i < strlen(str)/2; i++)
                {
                        temp = str[i];
                        str[i] = str[strlen(str) - i];
                        str[strlen(str) - i] = temp;
                }
        printf("%s\n", str);
        }
        else
                printf("FOFF!\n");
}
```

When I input `abcdef` the output is `afedcb`. Why is the first character not being shifted to the end?

Comment: use debugger to track the bug.I think there is somthing wrong with strlen(str)/2 in for loop.

Comment: Your indices `strlen(str)-i` are incorrect. They need to be `strlen(str)-i-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a bug in your code

```
str[i] = str[strlen(str) - i]; // should be str[i] = str[strlen(str) - i -1];
```

And

```
str[strlen(str) - i] = temp ; // should be str[strlen(str) - i - 1] = temp;
```

otherwise when i == 0, str[strlen(str) - 0] which is `\0`;

This is the fully working code

```
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include "string.h"


    int main()
    {
            char temp;
            char *str = NULL;
            int read, i;
            size_t len = 20;


            read = getline(&str, &len, stdin);
            if (read > -1)
            {
                    str[read - 1] = '\0';
                    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str)/2; i++)
                    {
                            temp = str[i];
                            str[i] = str[read - 1 - i - 1];
                            str[strlen(str) - i - 1] = temp;
                    }
                    printf("%s\n", str);
            }
            else
                    printf("FOFF!\n");
    }
```

Comment: This is correct because while giving input '\n' is taken so he try to remove it by str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0'; ,that is at end he would have 2 '\0'.

Comment: Since `read` tells you how many characters were read including the newline, you don't need to use `strlen()` at all; you can use `read` or `read-1`.  Also, if `read` is zero, you would access the element before the start of the array.  It is a fine point whether the return value from `getline()` can ever be zero; I think not (so this objection may be moot), but caution suggests that you should be very careful with short lines.  If `read` is one, the only character is a newline, for example.  Repeatedly calling `strlen()` on a string that doesn't change length at all is a bit wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code to reverse string.

```
void reverse(char str[],int len)
{
    char c;
    int i;
    int n=(len-1)/2;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        c=str[len-i-1];
        str[len-i-1]=str[i];
        str[i]=c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but your answer likely was downvoted because although your code solves the problem, the main question was what is wrong with the code in the question, not how to solve the problem.  Also, FYI, you should replace the `<=` in the loop with `<`; on an odd-length string, you end up swapping the central character with itself.  Harmless, but unnecessary.

Comment: Thx @JonathanLeffler, I think downvoting shouldn't be allowed without an explanation!

Comment: @koodawg: it has often been suggested on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=comment+downvote); it has never been accepted.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i have tested my code with < which give wrong result , but us working correct with <=.

Comment: You're right; it isn't as simple as changing `<=` to `<`.  I'm right too in that on odd length strings, your code does swap the centre element with itself. If you calculate `n = len / 2;` then you can use `<`; if you use `n = (len - 1)/2;`, then you need to use `<=` and tolerate the swap with itself. I apologize for not noting that extra necessary change originally.